# Can $12n+5$ be written as $2x^2+5y^2+9z^2+xyz$ with $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. By the Gauss-Legendre theorem on sums of three squares, for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we can write $4n+1$ as $x^2+y^2+z^2$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$.

Motivated by this, here I pose the following question.

**Question.** Whether for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we can write $12n+5$ as $2x^2+5y^2+9z^2+xyz$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$?

I have verified that for each $n=0,\ldots,3\times10^5$ we can write $12n+5$ as $2x^2+5y^2+9z^2+xyz$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$. For example, $12\times21030+5=252365$ has a unique desired representation:
$$252365 = 2\times32^2 + 5\times126^2+9\times39^2+32\times126\times39.$$

I guess that the question has a positive answer. Any ideas to approach this?

Comment: I have extended my check. The question has a positive answer for  $n\le 10^6$.

Comment: The motivation is in a deep (structural) contrast with the question. In the motivation we have a homogeneous quadratic form, $q(\ (x,y,z)\ ):=x^2+y^2+z^2$, and for such a form it is a natural question to ask for the numbers representing it. In the question, there is a "mixed" monomial part, we have terms of degree two, and one monomial of degree three. (So we do not even have a trilinear form to be extracted.) Also, the restriction to natural numbers (versus integers) is somehow unnatural. Why is this question of interest? If it is / would be solved, which is the benefit?

Comment: If you think that only homogenous diophntine equations with integer (not natural number) solutions are interesting, I have nothing else to say.

Comment: I am thinking that structural problems are of interest. So $\Bbb Z$ is a ring, the ring of integers. The natural numbers are not building a ring. Diophantine equations are usually involving integers. See the first proposition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation. Methods like going $p$-adically are working best with integers. Well, positivity is maybe related to the $\infty$-place, so i was saying that this condition is "somehow unnatural". This is to make clear what i was writing above. Else, above there are still questions, some potential answerer may be helped to start.